# Community Promotion Ads — 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads

You lost your “beta” label in 2019, so welcome to your very first edition of **Community Promotion Ads**, for the year of 2020!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful and interesting martial arts blogs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/606).

Comment: I think this site lacks enough meta users for these to get 6 votes. Is there any way that it could be changed to a lower number, like 3 or maybe 4?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Only the Strongest - The only capoeira podcast formed by natural selection. Survival of the fittest - no idea is safe. Teaching advice, training tips, concepts, and plenty of infighting from your hosts.]

Comment: My favorite Capoeira podcast. Weekly broadcasts.

Comment: By who? You should add the name ...

Comment: :) It's information available once you click through. They aren't big names in Capoeira, só losing their names isn't going to draw people in.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was something like the one by Joe Rogan, like there is this one host who calls in guests ... So I upvoted it, we need three more.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Judo Chop Suey Podcast hosted by Dave Roman]

Comment: It's a judo podcast covering international competition and grassroots development in the US.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Ramsey Dewey is no-nonsense in his advice, non-dismissive of Traditional Martial Arts (he acknowledges that few train under actual combat situations, but also notes that many people don't learn them to fight), and very easy on the ears (according to one of his videos, this is actually a side effect of the injury that retired him from MMA. He has to talk slowly and clearly or his speech gets confused). I've contacted him for an "official" ad image, but for now, a screenshot from one of this videos with text.

Comment: Incidentally, he approved of the image.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Punching and kicking bags for all skill levels]

Comment: The most pro-recommended standing punching/kickboxing bags in the world!