# Lowering required votes for community ads

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked this question on meta, and they told me to ask it here and have a moderator raise it to S.E.

If anyone has noticed, the [community promotion ads](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/community-promotion-ads-2020) post has been sitting in meta for a while. There are 3 ad suggestions, all 3 with 2 votes. It's been that way for at least two months, and it's most likely going to stay that way. We need the required vote minimum lowered on our site. Since this site has a low number of users, and a very small percentage of those users are MA meta users, it would be very hard for a given ad proposal to get the required 6 votes. It's not that the community isn't interested, it's just that there isn't enough community! S.E. isn't going to make this change to our site (or any other small sites) unless the issue is raised to them by the community. And that's us! Community promotion ads shouldn't only show up on larger sites, they should show up on ours too! They can be helpful because they can help users find a product or service that could be beneficial to them. And there's no reason for us to NOT have that. Nothing bad will come from raising this concern higher up.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346850/how-can-the-required-number-of-votes-for-community-promotion-ads-be-lowered-on-s) is the question I asked on Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main site has about 7300 users, and Meta has 567 users. I don't think we're lacking *numbers*, we're lacking *interaction*.

The right way to drive that interaction is to do what you've done - ask questions that grab people's attention and make them want to interact. Also look to dig up more contenders for advertising - interaction directly with the original post will also help attract eyeballs and vote clicking fingers to it.

Comment: So, just post more questions? That might work, but don't you think that 6 votes is still to high? There's no way that more than 6 of the 567 users are active within a given time, and even if there was, that wouldn't mean that all of them, or even most of them, would cast a vote. If you look at the number of views, compared to the time that the question has been around, compared to how many votes the answer has, you will see that the number is low, no matter what.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea is to tag the community ads post [tag:featured], to get site members to vote on ad ideas and drive attention to the ad post?

Comment: @gparyani I tagged the community ads meta-question as featured on 30 March, and it remains featured now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced this should be escalated. Why is it beneficial to have specific ads? Isn't the lack of enthusiasm indication of what the community thinks?

Comment: I'm not so sure that it's a lack of community enthusiasm, rather a lack of community. I mean, there are MAYBE four active meta users for this site.